# Handling simultaneous MySQL queries from different users

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I have a PHP/MySQL sign-up system that limits the number of people who can sign up for something. So, let's say there are 5 spots available, and 4 of them are already full. Now, 2 different users who are logged in submit a form **at the exact same time** that executes a MySQL query to add that person to the list.

Simplified, the PHP logic looks something like:

```
if($numberOfSpotsTaken < 5) {
    //add user to list
}
else {
    //don't add user to list
}
```

Now, because the users both submit the request at the same time, when the code checks to see how many spots are taken, it will be under 5 for both. What ends up happening is that both requests go through and 6 people end up on the list when the limit is supposed to be 5.

**How can I prevent this situation so that two (or more) users who submit a request at the same time can't bypass the limit of how many people can sign up?**

Comment: How you determine logged in users, have you keep any value in your database for those who are logged in ?

Comment: Heera, could you please clarify your question? I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: I'm asking how you determine how many users have logged in, where you put that data ? Do you change any status in your user table for logged in users ?

Comment: I use PHP sessions. No, there is no status change in the database table when someone logs in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by using PDO's `beginTransaction()`, `rollBack()`, and `commit()` methods to prevent overbooking.

Simplified, here's what I did:

```
<?php

$db->beginTransaction();

//add to list
$sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO...");
$sth->execute();

//select count from list
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT ... FROM ...");
$sth->execute();

//check to see whether the list is overbooked -- in this case, 5 is the list limit
if($sth->rowCount() > 5) {
    $db->rollBack();
}
else {
    $db->commit();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL only allows a single user to write to a single database at a single time.

I would recommend that you check on page load AND on submission.  If you are not checking everything (user submitted data, availability, etc) server-side, then you're going to make your scripts very insecure.

If you really really think somebody might slip in in a few microseconds, then have the script check after 'success' to see how many entries there are.  If there are too many, remove the latest entries down to the correct number.

Make sure you think this though and handle any errors :D

Answer (score 0):

I went looking for an answer for you and found this:

[Transactional DB Locking](http://www.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=16626)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solution looks similar to PDO's beginTransaction() and rollBack() methods. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php

Answer (score 0):

Technically your scenario can happen, but it's almost impossible. MySQL does allow multiple inserts which is where obtaining an exclusive lock comes in. See MySQL's documentation here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html

Comment: This issue has actually happened twice in the past few weeks. Although I gave an example of 5 spots in the question, the reality is that there are many more spots than that with a lot of people trying to sign up. I'll check out that link, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "the exact same moment" bit, not the overbooking. I know from experience that it happens. Otherwise, why bother creating transaction locks? :) Good luck

Comment: Do you think transaction locks would be a big performance hit if there were perhaps hundreds of queries executed?

Comment: Performance hit, yes, but for hundreds, not a big one.  That said, you know the pace things come in at.  In the past, I've set a threshold at which I would start requesting a transaction lock, ie if you have 2000 open spots and you get about 100 requests per hour and about 40 in the last 10 minutes before closing out your event, perhaps start requesting transaction locks in the last 50 or so.